# Boost::Python and Qt - QImage assignment operator - dll load failure

Tags: python, c++, qt, boost

I am trying to use boost::python to link QCustomPlot to a PyQt4 application.  I do not need to do anything in python with the QCustomPlot only pass data to it for display / interaction.  This means there are no signals / slots between C++ and python.  The 2 parts are standalone apart from adding a QCustomPlot widget to the PyQt application and it receiving data.

The problem is I receive a "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found." when I try and import the compiled C++ pyd (dll) file containing QCustomPlot.  I have tried using sip (qcustomplot_python) as well with the same results.

After some investigation I have been able to recreate the error in a short code example.  First define the class you want to use to interface between Python and C++ (Interface.h).

```
#ifndef INTERFACE_H
#define INTERFACE_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QImage>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>

class Interface : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    Interface() {
        img = QImage();

        QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout();
        layout->addWidget(new QLabel("Hello World"));
        this->setLayout(layout);
    }

private:

    QImage img;
};

#endif // INTERFACE_H
```

Next define the boost::python bindings (py_expose.cpp).

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

#include "Interface.h"
#include <QWidget>

long int unwrap(QObject* ptr) {
    return reinterpret_cast<long int>(ptr);
}

template <typename T>
T* wrap(long int ptr) {
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(ptr);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(QImage_interface)
{
    boost::python::class_<QObject, QObject*, boost::noncopyable>("QObject", boost::python::no_init)
        .def("unwrap", unwrap)
        .def("wrap", boost::python::make_function( wrap<QObject>, boost::python::return_value_policy<boost::python::return_by_value>() ))
        .staticmethod("wrap");

    boost::python::class_<QWidget, boost::python::bases<QObject>, QWidget*, boost::noncopyable>("QWidget")
        .def("wrap", boost::python::make_function( wrap<QWidget>, boost::python::return_value_policy<boost::python::return_by_value>() ))
        .staticmethod("wrap");

boost::python::class_<Interface, boost::python::bases<QWidget>, Interface*, boost::noncopyable>("Interface")
        .def("wrap", boost::python::make_function( wrap<Interface>, boost::python::return_value_policy<boost::python::return_by_value>() ))
        .staticmethod("wrap");
}
```

And now the python script to run.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

import QImage_interface
import sip

def toQt(object, type):
    ptr = object.unwrap()
    return sip.wrapinstance(ptr, type)

def fromQt(object, type):
    ptr = sip.unwrapinstance(object)
    return type.wrap(ptr)


class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.custom_plot = toQt(QImage_interface.Interface(), QtGui.QWidget)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.custom_plot)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And finally the QtCreator project.

```
QT = core gui

TARGET = QImage_interface
TARGET_EXT = .pyd

TEMPLATE = lib

CONFIG += shared

HEADERS += \
    Interface.h

SOURCES += \
    py_expose.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += $$(BOOST_ROOT) $$(PYTHON_INCLUDE)
LIBS += -L$$(BOOST_ROOT)/lib32-msvc-10.0 -lboost_python-vc100-mt-gd-1_55 -lC:/Python27/libs/python27
```

I am using PyQt4 built against Qt 4.8.4 and msvc-10.0 (32-bit).  The DLL load failure disappears if the line `img = QImage();` is removed but this is not a practical fix.

**EDIT:** Updating to Python 3.3 and PyQt5.2.1 (Qt 5.2.0) solves the problem.